# iMacros simple if else if tag has empty value set to default value

Tags: imacros

I am new to Imacros and  simply trying to extract order information from a page and sometimes the order information contains a telephone number sometimes not.

I want to have a simple if else statement in imacros  script to check if the phone number is null/ empty, if it is use my default phone number in its place, any help with this would be useful, thanks in advance

```
VERSION BUILD=8070701 RECORDER=CR

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0

TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmSubmit ATTR=ID:dayphone2 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR7 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL


'THIS IS THE ACTION I NEED - NOT IN THE CORRECT IMACROS FORMAT
if (VAR7 == NULL) { SET !VAR7 = '0800 00097777}
```

I need VAR7 set to my default phone number  if the value is empty from the extraction

thank for looking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imacros+javascript

Answer (score 2):

With command "EVAL" it's a simple thing:

```
SET !VAR7 EVAL("if (\"{{!VAR7}}\" == 'NULL') '0800 00097777'; else \"{{!VAR7}}\";")
```

Check only that !VAR7 is really NULL, but not "" (for example).